# Fastest way to find whether a file exists in a number of gzipped tarballs?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

Is there a more efficient way to do this other than using `tar tf` and checking the output of every file against the file that I'm looking for?

This is the way I do it right now, but it's very slow (there are about 600-1000 archives that fit the `search_patterns`):

```
ARRAY=()
ARRAY[0]=/path/to/archives/*search_pattern1*
ARRAY[1]=/path/to/archives/*search_pattern2*
ARRAY[2]=/path/to/archives/*search_pattern3*

for f in ${ARRAY[@]}
do
    if [[ $f =~ "matching_pattern1" ]]; then
        if tar -tf "$f" | grep "matching_pattern2" ; then
            printf "%s\n" $f;
            exit 0;
        fi
    fi
done
```

For what it's worth, my `search_patterns` are 3 consecutive days, and I want first to find the archives that match the `matching_pattern1` and then look through all these archives for `matching_pattern2` and output the `tar` file that contains it.

Comment: Do you have a literal file name or a file glob (for the file inside the tarball)?

Comment: You are probably better off not sticking globs into single array indices like that but instead letting the globs fill the array indices directly. `arr=(/path/to/archives/*search_pattern1* /path/to/archives/*search_pattern2* /path/to/archives/*search_pattern3*)`.

Comment: @EtanReisner it's a glob too

Comment: Do you need to do this regularly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't many shortcuts, `tar` files are sequential in nature, the best you can do is to process each tar file at most once (and possibly multiple files in [parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)). With GNU `tar` when searching a tar file you can do:

```
tar --wildcards -tzf file.tgz pattern [pattern...]
parallel -tk --tag tar --wildcards -tzvf ::: file*.tgz ::: "pattern"
```

using multiple patterns, matching file names will be displayed and exit code 0 if any are found. Remember to use "**" for a glob to match across directories.

*However*, if you're only looking for a single pattern per tar file, this really won't be measurably faster than your existing approach. GNU `tar` has optimizations for seekable tar files, but compression will counteract any benefits. Tar files can be incremental, split, updated and even contain multiple copies of the same file, there is no alternative to scanning the whole file (even though most tar files are not so complex).

If this is a recurring task, you might consider keeping an index file when the archives are created:

```
tar -czvf file.tgz files [...]  > file.idx
```

or if you use GNU tar, add: `--index-file=file.idx` instead, one `-v` is filenames only, with `-vv` the index file will contain the full details as would be shown by `-tv`. (There does not appear to be a `--index-file0` nul delimited option at this time.)

(In case it is useful, there are also alternatives to `tar` for this, see https://serverfault.com/questions/59795/is-there-a-smarter-tar-or-cpio-out-there-for-efficiently-retrieving-a-file-store )

Answer (score 2):

If it's an one time operation and you have regular tar files (not gzipped), I would suggest using `strings` to extract all ASCII strings from the tar files, check the output with grep, and untar only those files for which the output matches your pattern. Filenames are kept in cleartext so `strings` will likely show them to you:

```
$ strings file.tar | grep test
test
test.c
test.c
test.js
test.pl
```

and `strings` *may* work a bit faster than `tar tf`.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately the files are also gzipped, I somehow forgot to put that in the OP

Comment: Then I don't think there is a faster way of doing that. If you have more than one computer and a fast network, think about doing that in parallel on several computers with different sets of files :)

Answer (score 1):

You are relying on word splitting in that for loop. That's not a good idea (and isn't safe for oddly named files). You are better off letting the globs fill your array directly.

```
arr=(/path/to/archives/*search_pattern1* /path/to/archives/*search_pattern2* /path/to/archives/*search_pattern3*)
```

and using `for f in "${arr[@]}"`.

Then something like this might work (it could be much faster for tarballs that have the file if it was a static file name but a glob is always going to scan the whole tarball).

```
for f in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if tar -tf "$f" "matching_glob" &>/dev/null; do
        echo "File found in $f"
    fi
done
```